# How to display text if Product Type is Equal to?

Tags: phtml, magento-2.2.5

I'm trying to display some text IF `Product Type` = `General`. This edit is being made within a phtml file.

How'd I'd normally do it for a `Product Attribute` called `Example`

```
<?php $_product = $block->getProduct(); ?>

<?php if ($_product->getExample()): ?>
    <div>
        <p>Example</p>
    </div>
<?php endif; ?>
```

I'd also like to know how that could be achieved by checking for an `Attribute Set`.

Comment: Do you need to check attribute set condition? or any attribute condition?

Comment: For example, I'd want to check if the `Attribute Set` of the Product was called "Test".

Comment: Check my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The alternate way to do this,
You need to set those attribute value only for those products, for which you want to show that. And you need to code like this.

```
<?php $_product = $block->getProduct(); ?>

<?php if ($_product->getExample() !== '' && $_product->getExample() !== null): ?>
    <div>
        <p>Example</p>
    </div>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Comment: `$_product->getExample() != ''` and `$_product->getExample() != null` is the same, so no need to ask for both. it differs only if you use `!==` instead of `!=`

Comment: Yes, I update answer.

Answer (score 1):

You can get attribute set name by following code:

```
$objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
$attributeSet = $objectManager->create('Magento\Eav\Api\AttributeSetRepositoryInterface');
$attributeSetRepository = $attributeSet->get($_product->getAttributeSetId());
$attribute_set_name = $attributeSetRepository->getAttributeSetName();
if($attribute_set_name == 'Test'){
    //Do your stuff
}
```

Answer (score -1):

**You can try like below (its for simple products) :**

```
$_product->getTypeId() == \Magento\Catalog\Model\Product\Type::TYPE_SIMPLE
```

You can check for required product types in file

```
vendor\Magento\Catalog\Model\Product\Type.php
```

Comment: I'll try that in a bit. How do you think I'd do this for `Attribute Set`?